# Why is dereferenced element in const vector of int pointers mutable?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, constants, operator-precedence

I am not sure the true meaning of `const vector<int *>` so I compiled the code below to get an idea but am now more confused.

```
vector<int *> v;
int x = 1, y = 2;
v.push_back(&x);
v.push_back(&y);

const vector<int *> w = v;
w[0] = &y;   //failed. Element is a constant pointer?
*(w[0]) ++;  //failed. Element pointer references to constant value?
```

If I had stopped here, I would have assumed that `const vector<int *>` is a vector of `const int * const`, but then I tried the following which clearly contradicted that assumption.

```
*(w[0]) += 3; //passed. Value not constant?
*(w[0]) = 20; //passed. Why...
```

Now `*(w[0])` for reason unknown to me obviously treats `++` and `+=` and assignment differently. I convinced myself that `const vector` only declares a constant object of the `vector` class and that the above results might depend on the actual implementation of the operator overloading of `vector` class. But I can't wrap my head around this. Can anyone help explain, please?

If it is relevant, I used g++ 4.2 on a Mac.

Comment: You might find this interesting: Change the post to pre-increment and see what happens on the second failure example. `++*(w[0]);`.

Comment: I think a big source of confusion is writing `*(w[0]) ++;` instead of `(*w[0]) ++;` (which I think was likely the intended result). Operator precedence can be a little tricky sometimes.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Why is dereferenced element in const vector of int pointers mutable?

For `const vector<int *>`, the element would be `const` pointer to non-`const`, i.e. `int * const`, so you can modify the object pointed by the pointer, but not the pointer itself.

According to [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), postfix increment operator has higher precedence than `operator*`, so `*(w[0]) ++;` is equivalent to

```
* ((w[0]) ++);
```

The increment on the pointer is performed at first, then it fails. `w[0] = &y;` is also trying to modify the pointer, so it fails too.

On the other hand, `(*w[0]) ++;` (i.e. increment on the pointee) would be fine. And the following statements are fine too, because they're both modifying the objects pointed by the pointer, not the pointers.

```
*(w[0]) += 3; //passed.
*(w[0]) = 20; //passed.
```

Answer (score 9):

It's a matter of [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

When you do `*(w[0]) ++` you attempt to modify the *pointer*.

When you do `*(w[0]) += 3` you modify the data pointed to by the pointer.

Answer (score 6):

`w` is a `const vector<int *>`. The `const` *qualifier* is applied to the vector. Therefore, the corresponding `const` member function will be used for the `operator[]`:

`const_reference operator[]( size_type pos ) const;`

Since the vector is `const`-qualified and contains elements of type `int *` ( and not `const int *`), the type of the expression `w[0]` is `int * const&` (instead of `const int *&`). That is, it is a *reference to a constant pointer to an `int`* and not a *reference to a pointer to a constant `int`*: the *constness* is applied to the the pointer itself, not to the data being pointed.

By doing `*(w[0]) += 3` you are not modifying the *value of the pointer the vector returns* (which is `const`), but *the value this pointer is pointing to*. Since this pointer is of type `int * const` (and not `const int *`), you can modify what it is pointing to, so it does work. However, doing `w[0] = &y` is performing an assignment on a constant pointer, so it does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

`const vector<T>` lets you access its elements as `T const &` (*i.e.* `const T &`). In this case, `T` is `int *`, so this is `int * const &`, a const reference to a pointer that points to an `int`. The pointer is constant, but the int is not.

The type of the vector would have needed to be `vector<int const *>` (*i.e.* `vector<const int*>`) in which case the elements would be accessed via `int const * const &`.

Bottom line, constness is transitive with templates but not with pointers. And if you put pointers in templates, you get a bit of both behaviors.